# I cant get all files of array

Tags: php, laravel

whatever I pass an array of files, I always get the first file.So what should I do to get all files in an array?

I have defined File table which contains **path, title,card_id**.
I want to store all file's path,title which are coming from create method in controller as an **array** of request.

in controller,

```
public function create(Request $request,$card_id)
    {

      $files = $request->file('file');
        foreach ($files as $file){
             print_r($file->getClientOriginalName());
        }
}
```

Comment: "I pass an array of files". Where? How?

Comment: try `$request->files;`

Comment: show us something, how you storing in your controller code, or your view form how you are sending files

Answer (score 2):

Make sure it's an array:

```
<input type="file" name="photos[]" multiple>
```

And then this will be an array of files:

```
foreach ($request->photos as $photo)
```

Comment: Not in frontend, it is actually coming from routes

Comment: @DhruvKoshiyar what you mean by "it is actually coming from routes"?

Comment: @DhruvKoshiyar still don't get it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $files = Input::file('file');

  foreach ($files as $file) {
                     //do stuff
  }
```

Don't forget to `use Input;` at the top.